# How to securely process transactions

Tags: php, e-commerce

I am creating a service where users have to pay for certain product. Now, I am struggling with the transaction part.

I am creating a transaction if users get to the checkout page. The payment gateway has the following URLs:

```
ReturnUrl -> The URL the costumer is being redirected to after a succesfull payment (after clicking "Back to Webshop")
NotifyUrl -> The URL (server-to-server call) thats being called when the user finishes his payment, when the costumer is being redirected back via ReturnUrl
CallbackUrl -> The URL thats being called when the user closes his browser after a succesfull payment, without clicking the "Back to Webshop" button, and hence not being redirected via ReturnUrl
```

Now, I am struggling with how to securely set the transaction to completed when they return to either NotifyUrl or CallbackUrl.
I am generating a token when I am putting the transaction to the database so unauthorized users can't modify/change anything. But I am sending the token with POST to my payment provider, which means if they know what url to send a GET request to with all the information such as token en transaction_id, they could browse there without actually paying and tricking my server into thinking the request came from my payment processor.

How would I go about properly doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow your logic. What exactly could someone browse and where? And re your saying that your transaction ids are serial (so someone could figure it out) and that your are not checking whether a request comes from your payment provider?

Answer (score 0):

At least you should verify the origin of the server-to-server call (ip address or domain) to be sure it's the payment processor who made the request.

Some payment processors (multisafepay) just send a wake-up message to NotifyUrl, simply stating that the status of payment such-and-so has changed. Then your server can make a secure call to the payment processor requesting the exact details and update the local status accordingly.

Furthermore it's always wise to use ssl in these scenarios.